# character replacement via command line

Tags: c, argv

I am trying to write a linux command called replace which will replace characters in a file. I hope to call it like so:

```
$./replace I XY test.txt
```

In this example, `test.txt` contains the words "THIS IS A TEST FILE"

How can I replace the character `'I'` with `"XY"`. I have tried to use a buffer such as the code given below, but due to the fact that the buffer and argv are declared differently, it produces an error. Furthermore, `'I'` is stored in one array element, whereas `"XY"` requires two. Does there exist a workaround for this?

Consider the `text.txt` example:

```
[T][H][I][S][ ][I][S][ ][A][ ][T][E][S][T][ ][F][I][L][E]
```

In this example, the third index (which contains `'I'`) must be replaced with `"XY"`

Here's my code, which has the issue described above:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 4096

/*replace i xy data.txt */
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int in_fd, out_fd, n_chars, BufElement,j;
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];
    in_fd=open(av[3], O_RDWR);

    /*Read characters from file to buffer*/
    while ( (nread = read(in_fd , buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0 )
    {
        for (BufElement=0;BufElement < nread;BufElement++)
        {
            for (j=0; j < strlen(av[1]); j++)
            {
                if (buf[BufElement] == av[1][j])
                    buf[BufElement] = av[2]; /*ERROR*/
            }/*for*/
        }/*for*/
    }/*while*/
}/*main*/
```

Comment: Why not just post the code here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace substring in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659694/how-to-replace-substring-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

`buf[BufElement]` is a character and `av[2]` is a string( character pointer specifically ). You cannot equate the two like you've done( `buf[BufElement] = av[2];`) Also, even it was possible, you cant simple replace 1 byte with 2 bytes in a buffer easily in C. It will overwrite the next character.

You need to copy the file contents till the match is found in a temp buffer, append your replace string to this temp buffer and then copy the remaining contents of the file.

Comment: so just to verify. I copy "this is a test file" character by character to a buffer. WHILE I am copying, I check if argv[2] == i. If there is a match, then put X Y into buffer and copy the rest of the file into buffer.                                                              But then I have to specifically say if argv[2] == 'i' then put XY. The user should be able to replace any character with his choice of characters

Comment: Yes, correct, something on these lines.if( buffer[i]==argv[1][0]), then buffer[i]='X', buffer[i+1]='Y' and then continue like buffer[i]=fgetc(fp)

Comment: thanks for your reply sir.                                                                Is there any general way of doing this? buffer[i]='X'. For example, if user enters $./replace I ZS test.txt then I should be replaced by Z and S. Hence, why I put buffer[i] = argv[2] (but of course this is error)

Comment: you can do simply do `strncpy(buffer+i,argv[2],BUFFERSIZE-i)`. Note that `buffer+i` is a pointer but `buffer[i]` is a character. Then you can continue by readjusting the value of `i` like `i+=strlen(argv[2])`