# Replace char array in other char array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, realloc

I have a char array and I want to replace `1*` or `2*` for `myDirectory1` or `myDirectory2`

Ex: `C:/1*/file.txt` -> `C:/MDirectory1/file.txt`
Ex: `C:/2*/file.txt` -> `C:/MDirectory2/file.txt`

My code seems to works but I do not understand some things:

Is okay to initialize a dynamic char array like this?

```
char *cad = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
if (!cad) exit(1);
```

Is okay to use realloc when I want to insert the char array inside the other?

```
realloc(*cad, sizeRep + strlen(auxi) + 1);
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replaceString(char **cad) {
    int sizeRep;
    char *auxi = *cad, *plec;
    char replace[500];
    plec = strchr(*cad, '*');
    switch (*(plec - 1)) {
      case '1':
        strcpy(replace, "myDirectory1");
        break;
      case '2':
        strcpy(replace, "MyDirectory2");
    }
    sizeRep = strlen(replace);
    realloc(*cad, sizeRep + strlen(auxi) + 1);
    memmove(plec + strlen(replace) - 1, plec + 1, strlen(plec));
    memmove(plec - 1, replace, sizeRep);
    return auxi;
}

int main() {
    char *cad = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
    if (!cad) exit(1);
    strcpy(cad, "C:/2*/file.txt");
    printf("%s", replaceString(&cad));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace substring in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659694/how-to-replace-substring-in-c)

Comment: `realloc(*cad,sizeRep+strlen(auxi)+1);` --> `*cad = realloc(*cad, sizeRep+strlen(auxi)+1);` and You should think that `auxi` and `plec`  become invalid after `realloc`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  if(!cad)return NULL; is it enough with this line?

Comment: Do You talk about `if (!cad) exit(1);` ? It is more helpful to output a message explaining the cause.

Comment: I want to use if(!cad)return NULL;  after realloc to prevent auxi and plec from becoming invalid.

Comment: If `realloc` succeeds (in most cases) the previous content is copied to the newly reserved area. So pointers pointing to some of the old areas will be invalid.

Comment: If `realloc` fails, `auxi` can be used, but after that event processing can not continue. It is reasonable to return `NULL` if you want error handling to be left to the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors:

- you do not check if `*` was found and if it was found at an offset greater than `0`.
- you do not copy the null terminator.
- your computations are off by one.
- you do not store the return value of `realloc()`
- you access a location in the string that was reallocated, this has potential undefined behavior if the string was moved. Use the offset instead.
- the replacement for `2*` has a different case from that of `1*`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replaceString(char **cad) {
    char *auxi = *cad;
    size_t len = strlen(auxi);
    char *plec = strchr(auxi, '*');

    if (plec && plec > auxi) {
        size_t offset = plec - auxi - 1;
        size_t sizeRep;
        const char *replace = NULL;

        switch (auxi[offset]) {
          case '1':
            replace = "myDirectory1";
            break;
          case '2':
            replace = "myDirectory2";
            break;
          default:
            return auxi;
        }
        sizeRep = strlen(replace);
        // reallocate auxi: -2 for the characters removed, +1 for the null termnator
        auxi = realloc(auxi, len - 2 + sizeRep + 1);
        if (auxi == NULL)
            return NULL;
        memmove(auxi + offset + sizeRep, auxi + offset + 2, len - offset - 2 + 1);
        memmove(auxi + offset, replace, sizeRep);
        *cad = auxi;
    }
    return auxi;
}

int main(void) {
    char *cad = strdup("C:/2*/file.txt");
    if (!cad)
        exit(1);
    printf("%s\n", replaceString(&cad));
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

`realloc()` is a notorious source of problems, leading to undefined behavior and memory leaks. You might want to change your function to use a simpler API, always allocate the return value, without side effects on the arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replaceString(const char *src) {
    size_t size = strlen(src) + 1;
    size_t offset = 0, matchlen = 0, replace_len = 0;
    const char *replacement = "";
    const char *p;
    char *dest;

    if ((p = strstr(src, "1*")) != NULL) {
        offset = p - src;
        match_len = 2;
        replacement = "myDirectory1";
        replacement_len = strlen(replacement);
    } else
    if ((p = strstr(src, "2*")) != NULL) {
        offset = p - src;
        match_len = 2;
        replacement = "myDirectory2";
        replacement_len = strlen(replacement);
    }
    dest = malloc(size - match_len + replacement_len);
    if (dest) {
        memcpy(dest, src, offset);
        memcpy(dest + offset, replacement, replacement_len);
        memcpy(dest + offset + replacement_len,
               src + offset + match_len, size - offset - match_len);
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str = replaceString("C:/2*/file.txt");
    if (!str)
        exit(1);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is no major issues that I can see. But I like to add come comments.

- After calling "`realloc`" function the value of `*cad` could ne invalid if there in no enough memory to allocate. So be conscious about it as BLUEPIXY suggested in his comment.
- The `*cad` pointer use differently in in various location. In the `main` it is a pointer. But in the `replaceString` it is a double pointer. Pragmatically there is no issue since the scope is different. But it is preferable to avoid such usage.